# Обновление сцены JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть `ArrayList` из `TextField`, в программе необходимо удалять `TextField` (с этим проблем нет), но на экране приложения все равно остается этот удаленный элемент.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обновить экран, или можно решить проблему по другому?

Comment: приведите пример кода. Как вы удаляете элемент?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно вы присваиваете указателю `null` значение, это не удаляет `TextField` если он был добавлен в сцену. Что бы удалить элемент c панели надо, непосредственно, вызвать метод `remove()`.

Вот пример для понимания (при нажатии на кнопку, кнопка удаляется с панели):

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Remove Button");
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        final Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setLayoutX(100);
        btn.setLayoutY(80);
        btn.setText("Remove me=)");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                root.getChildren().remove(btn);
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```